# How to auto adjust image size in swift programatically

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Hi i am trying to add background image, but its not fitting with all device, its getting smaller in iPad, its getting bigger in iPhone devices

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "bg_100")!)
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: maybe you could try using CoreGraphics and it's `CGContextDrawTiledImage` method

Comment: 1. Explain Size of Image, which you are using . bg_100.

Comment: @ VS dimensions of image 1242 × 2208 pixels

Comment: So, you must put all sizes images, so it will be okay with all dimensions,

Comment: @VS k cool can u please mention the sizes if possible sorry i am new to iOS developing

Comment: [This site](http://iosres.com/) should help. It lists all the screen sizes you'll need

Comment: @VS cool you got it if not ping it